# SUM function to return null if null value exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT (SELECT cost FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.edate=>table1.edate) AS cost
FROM table1
WHERE table1.orderNo = 'CS119484568'
```

the above query returns:

```
cost
4
3
null
null
5
```

I want to get sum of all or null if any row have a null

```
SELECT SUM((SELECT cost FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.edate=>table1.edate)) AS cost
FROM table1
WHERE table1.orderNo = 'CS119484568'
```

Expected result NULL in the above case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Sum only if all rows are not null, else return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398437/mysql-sum-only-if-all-rows-are-not-null-else-return-null)

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain in more detail? Your examples don't make much sense. In the first one, the subquery will most likely return more than 1 row, so that can't be correct. Can you maybe give a sample of the data in `table1`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT
        case when count(*)=count(cost) then sum(cost) else null end
     FROM table1 t2
     WHERE t2.edate=>table1.edate
    ) AS cost
FROM table1
WHERE table1.orderNo = 'CS119484568'
```

This is based on the fact that `count()` only counts non-null values.

Comment: It returned same result as my 1st query. The subquery is meant to return `cost` and those cost would have nulls as well. The operation needs to be done on the resultset of subquery, not inside subquery. I hope i have explain clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if for this:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.edate=>table1.edate AND cost IS NULL), null, (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.edate=>table1.edate)) AS cost FROM table1 WHERE table1.orderNo = 'CS119484568'
```

Comment: Two subquries as you mentioned could maybe solve the problem, but I was trying to avoid it. Will look into it later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I would phrase your query as:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t1.edate >= tt1.edate THEN cost END)
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT edate
      FROM table1
      WHERE t1.orderNo = 'CS119484568'
     ) tt1;
```

Then I would use a `CASE` expression for your result:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(t1.edate >= tt1.edate AND cost IS NOT NULL) = 0  -- no nulls
             THEN SUM(CASE WHEN t1.edate >= tt1.edate THEN cost END)
        END)
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT edate
      FROM table1
      WHERE t1.orderNo = 'CS119484568'
     ) tt1;
```